# How do you manage component state in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm making a component that will keep track of text the user enters in an input and call a method when it's changed. I planned to store the input's value in state but `this` is undefined within the js file in /components. Here's what I've tried

```
export default function TalentSearch() {
  this.state = 'val';

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clicked}>click me</button>
      <input type="text" name="search" />
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your help ahead of time

Comment: There is no `this` in function components in this way. Suggested read [Function and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). Also read further about [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: Yup, there's no `this` access in functional components.

Comment: If anyone is using class based React.Component. 
Just a reminder to bind your handleClick function in the constructor.

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);


Spent 3 hours after forgetting it like an idiot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have defined here is a functional Component. Only class components can use `this`. So either you could change what you have to a class component or you can simply have state in a functional component using the `useState` hook like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react'; 

export default function TalentSearch() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("value")

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clicked}>click me</button>
      <input type="text" name="search" />
      <div>
        <p>{value}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Some notes**

- just call `value` anywhere within the component to get the current state and if you would like to change it use the set state function like this: `setValue(new state)`

Comment: If someone is using class based React.Component. 
Just a reminder to bind your handleClick function in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

NextJS is a superset of React WITH new features and strategy of bundling/optimization. so all features has in React is applicable. you might want to read as well their [features](https://nextjs.org/docs)

Happy Coding!